# Connecting to DynamoDB from on-premises web server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, vpn

My organization has an AWS presence, but no VPN nor Direct Connect to and from  our on-premises data center. We would still like to leverage DynamoDB in the short-term without having DirectConnect or a VPN connection in place. We will not be using any EC2 instances for our web services. Is it possible for an on--prem host to talk to DynamoDB without any AWS networking infrastructure in place....basically a call direct to the DynamoDB service without VPN or Direct Connect?

Comment: Do we still need same method? Or is there any new method now

Answer (score 2):

All you need is an Internet connection to access DynamoDB. Your on-premis servers will need to have access to make calls to the AWS API, which is publicly accessible over the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an VPC endpoint gateway to connect your server to Dynamo Db using amazon network

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/it_it/vpc/latest/privatelink/vpc-endpoints.html